# overflow:hidden not working on my div

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to get the footer at the bottom of my page to stay at the bottom of the page without the page content going over it. I'd want the page content to push the footer down.

I though `overflow: hidden` would work, but it doesn't.

[The problem.](http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/yorkshirecouriers/?p=1)

Comment: Please show some code here so the question can have values for future generations. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the height for the content to a min-height instead.

Comment: Thanks! Took the height out completely - I didn't even realise it was there.

Answer (score 1):

Place the footer at the bottom of the container by using this CSS code:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: -5px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
```